# php Maximum execution time to export hight volume CSV file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I want to export my database mysql into a CSV file, I can do that, but, I have a very large volume, this export need to have more time for exporting my file, but, I don't have control of my server to increase the maximum time execution So, the file is not loading completely, but just a half So, I 'am asking myself if there is a solution, to make a little break, and resume exports after that little break.. 
Or is there another solution ? 
Thank you very much

Comment: Doesn't really `ini_set()` work? There's still a way to make "breaks", but I think you could just set the max_execution_time via ini_set()

Comment: thank you very much, that works !
i use ini_set('max_execution_time', 9999);

Comment: Also depends how you're creating the csv file, etc

Comment: If you have such long running and memory consuming scripts, you should execute them via the console. The CLI SAPI does not have those limits set by default.